# Displaying information next to input onfocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hello I have a form with few input fields, I am want to display some information related to the particular field once user enter the text field. so far I have managed to do this:

```
 <tr>
 <td>Name&nbsp;</td>
 <td width="162"><input name="txtname" type="text" id="txtname"  /></td>
 <td width="333"><span class="style1"><br/>Enter Your Name, Preferably as per your PAN Card</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Father Name&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;<input name="txtfname" type="text" id="txtfname"  /></td>
 <td><span>Enter Your Father Name Preferably as per your PAN Card</span></td>
 </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PAN&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input name="txtpan" type="text" id="txtpan" onblur="checkPAN()" maxlength="10"  /></td>
        <td>Enter Your PAN No. carefully</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mobile Number&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input name="txtmb" type="text" id="txtmb" maxlength="10"  /></td>
        <td>Enter your Mobile No. we will be in touch with you with this No In case of any further details</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Confirm Mobile Number&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input name="txtmbcnfrm" type="text" id="txtmbcnfrm" maxlength="10"  /></td>
        <td>Reenter your Mobile No.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email Id&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input name="txtemail" type="text" id="txtemail" onchange="emailval()"  /></td>
        <td>Enter your Valid email ID to which you need to receive    Acknowledgement,   </td>
      </tr>
```

all information next to text fields should be hidden but when `onFocus` the particular information should be displayed, I can do this with `jquery` but I am confused how to get there.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What is your jquery code?

Comment: you can use `plcaholder`

Comment: is the information that you want to display the next `<td>` after `input`?

Comment: Please format your HTML first because somewhere you have used `<span>` and somewhere it is missing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input').parent().next().hide();
$('input').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).parent().next().show();
});
$('input').on('blur', function () {
    $(this).parent().next().hide();
});
```

here's the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/EqfJU/)